# Getting Encoded Data from a JWT

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I have a program that gets data from an API and uses JWT to communicate/authorize.  On the client side I need to get a few pieces of data that are encoded as claims in the JWT, rather than pinging the API again I thought it would be best to just get the info from the token so I wrote this quick method:

```
string GetTokenValue(string tokenType)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentAuth?.AccessToken)) return null;

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(CurrentAuth.AccessToken);
    return jwt.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == tokenType)?.Value;
}
```

This overall seems to work very well, however I have a few clients that are getting some errors with decoding.  Here is the relevant portion of the stack sent from one:

```
IDX12729: Unable to decode the header '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[] tokenParts, String rawData)
```

Is this not a recommended method to do this?  Why would it decode just fine on most machines but fail on a few?

Comment: Validate the token on `jwt.io`.  If it isn't valid, the issue isn't with your code (or at least, not *this* code)

Comment: Hm.  I will try but that's part of the issue right now, it's not doing it on mine just on a handful of user machines so I don't have their token to test and since it's PII the .NET framework removes it from the error stack so I really don't have current access to it.  I guess I can put in something to log the token but that requires a new build and for them to send me the logs after the error comes up which takes some time... Will start that process but was hoping there was a quicker way.

Comment: Does it fail consistently on a per-machine basis?  That is, do machines A-C all consistently work correctly, while machine D always fails?  That would *probably* indicate a cipher suite is missing from D.

Comment: I'm still trying to determine that, but so far it appears to be random.

Comment: In that case, I think your only choice right now is to gather more diagnostics to determine a pattern of behavior.  Fixes you implement in an attempt to fix this will be based on guesses at this point, and may cause harm (insofar as any change introduces an element of risk).  It might not be a problem with your code at all, e.g. some other system might be mutating the token inappropriately.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess that is correct.  I will see what I can gather and post back....

Comment: From what I remember from encrypted JWT claims. You need to decrypt the claims. First you need to find out whether you can access the keys from your code to decrypt the claims(know the algorithm used) or have method calls provided to you to decrypt it.

Comment: Claims aren't encrypted other than what JWT does by default, so the `JwtSecurityToken.Decode` should work and give me the correct value which it does in almost all cases except these few.  If it were an encryption issue I would think it would be everywhere...